# Sum the sum product

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumproduct

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[ESTIMATED DESIGN LENGTH (m)]*(Table1[CABLE TYPE]=automate!$A14)*(Table1[CABLE SIZE]=automate!$B14)*(Table1[YARD]=automate!$L$2)*(Table1[FROM LOCATION]<>Table1[TO LOCATION]))


=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[ESTIMATED DESIGN LENGTH (m)]*(Table1[CABLE TYPE]=automate!$A14)*(Table1[CABLE SIZE]=automate!$B14)*(Table1[YARD]=automate!$L$2)*(Table1[FROM LOCATION]=U3)*(Table1[TO LOCATION]=U3))
```

I would like to combine the above two formulas into one .(In short, sum the output of both the above formulas)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Charz! Could you show us a tiny sample of your input data and desired output, so we can work on it? Does it work, or do you get an error? You should try to cut your problem into smaller pieces, easier to work on, one by one. A clear code makes for a clear mind (and solves problems before they even appear)

Comment: You just need to replace the equal sign (`=`) of the second formula and replace with `+`. and join both lines. Maybe I am not following you